# Sharing image/link LinkedIn without app installation

Tags: swift

Is this necessary to **install LinkedIn app** while sharing an image and URL in  swift?

Comment: what do you mean by linked app?

Comment: @FangmingNing :linkedin app

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. In iOS, each app is in a separate *sandbox* and they cannot access information from each other. The only communication iOS allows you to make between apps is called a shared extension, and that **requires** your target app to be installed.